# Display text if attribute yes/no is set to YES in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, magento2.2

I'm trying to display something in the product page if a YES/NO attribute is set to YES.
Actually the only way I found to do this in multilingual magento 2.1.8 is :

```
if($_product->getAttributeText('MY_ATTRIBUTE') == 'Oui' || $_product->getAttributeText('MY_ATTRIBUTE') == 'Yes') {
    echo "Set to Yes";
} else {
    echo "Set to No";
};
```

This method needs to test the YES/NO answer for every language but I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use boolean value instead of string to check Yes/No value, use

`$_product->getData('attribute_code');`

```
<?php 

$yesNo = $_product->getData('attribute_code');

if($yesNo) {
    //value is set to Yes
} else {
    //value is set to No
}

?>
```

For example, if your attribute code is `myattribute` then you can also use `get()` method to get attribute method

> $_product->getMyattribute();

Comment: done but not enough reputation for now, new on this forum... but still thanks a lot